# java IOUtils: FileNotFoundException for url that works on browser

Tags: java, json, url, filenotfoundexception

I'm using Apache Commons IOUtils to read json data from a url. I'm getting FileNotFoundException with following code.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL(url), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

The same url is sending json data when tested on browser. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you provide more info regarding this problem?
Did you make sure, charset is correct?
I suppose you don't want to share this url, so maybe you can test on some another and share it with us.

Comment: What kind of information you are expecting? @Rumid

Comment: I tested the same code on some other url and got results. @Rumid

Comment: Re _What kind of information you are expecting?_, the information @Rumid mentioned in the comment would be a good start.

Comment: The charset is valid. I made sure of that. And as I said, the same code is working for other urls.

Comment: What is the HTTP code returned by the server ? Can you dump the traffic using something like Wireshark ?

Comment: @FlorentBayle The response code was 404.

Comment: @pkgajulapalli 404 is the HTTP code for Not Found, so, even if the server is correctly returning the json data, you will get a `FileNotFoundException` due to the return code.